# Reproduce a 3D Plot in R - Data as Matrix, custom axis & labels

Tags: r, plot, 3d, axis, label

It caused me quite a bit of a headache... but I got something, just not quite what I want... so, how can I reproduce the graph that I obtain from the equipment in R?

Original graph:

[image]

Now the data for that graph isn't 100% right (based on initial reading not minimal value during whole run) - so the plot I obtain is slightly different, but its a tiny difference, this is the corrected data:

```
    P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  P7  P8  P9  P10 P11 P12
5   1.356564    0   0   0   0   0   0.522919    0   0.269146    0.899989    0.996454    0
10  1.677049    0.016866    0   0   0   0.607368    0   0   0   0   0.742411    0
15  2.759722    0   0.602542    0   0.548937    0   0   0   0.148181    0   0.224815    0
20  2.383124    0   0   0   0   0   0.142785    0   0   0   0   0
25  2.194318    0.192807    0   1.278415    0   0.939523    0   0.112651    1.068246    1.16061 1.38776 0.676498
30  2.227332    0.658118    0.504237    0   0.760385    0.137248    0   0.376515    1.517327    1.266435    0.489707    0.974562
35  2.425865    0.571249    0.889235    1.315021    0.511195    0   0   0.414589    1.140811    1.845892    0.098323    0
40  2.56984 1.154292    1.163783    0.796667    0.746664    1.091858    1.122893    1.687882    2.061788    2.724509    2.308096    1.235134
45  2.71372 2.702534    2.704258    2.23746 2.314217    1.892822    1.86525 2.357875    2.554184    1.95893 1.188201    1.71474
50  2.84702 2.649788    2.113081    1.130567    1.357824    0.92954 1.419298    0.995268    0.548421    0.91788 0   0.024919
55  3.283965    0.843004    2.172512    1.763155    0.791001    0.874469    0.548028    1.039265    0.898974    0.227216    1.265553    0.581115
60  4.22087 2.367116    2.663145    2.21502 1.698861    0.571813    1.16839 0.594161    0.585841    0   0   0
65  3.905396    1.513722    2.426271    1.706694    1.34067 1.325783    0.490957    1.981992    0.235005    0.934454    0.940276    0.846207
70  4.649299    2.569352    2.811965    2.19341 2.635729    1.002647    0.915708    1.924824    0.794212    1.294401    1.157521    0.880585
75  4.103029    2.051672    2.758758    2.976522    2.188941    2.07245 2.149921    1.770336    2.685513    1.092814    1.355365    1.008754
80  4.531421    2.321935    3.618583    2.991384    2.537042    1.402546    1.431915    2.2841  1.387641    0.920552    2.044487    0.690089
85  5.199451    3.74389 3.736395    3.487242    2.09652 2.173166    1.911587    1.661859    1.755795    1.590398    1.545263    0.453356
90  5.3198  4.528225    4.328908    4.135772    2.374012    2.560562    2.979826    1.757164    2.13082 2.583608    2.522267    1.471753
95  5.676048    4.557345    5.179662    4.539891    4.028275    2.732066    3.528498    3.509869    2.473462    2.518212    2.026832    1.273347
100 6.53704 5.714319    6.743194    5.071138    3.87076 3.521927    2.769212    3.186856    2.466066    2.562069    1.546379    1.645076
105 6.870514    5.497576    5.636102    5.347473    4.649386    3.425513    3.473505    3.762797    2.721337    2.166123    2.366901    1.826227
110 6.813474    6.881328    5.637504    5.145343    3.972123    4.052656    2.745163    3.562568    4.188948    2.960847    3.056323    2.059925
115 7.719027    7.035191    7.379664    6.839802    5.063594    4.505035    4.020032    4.451296    4.72488 3.22288 3.514651    3.258859
120 8.504394    8.382436    7.485067    6.26145 5.311175    4.512194    4.223568    3.851785    3.984909    2.583755    3.97142 1.825233
125 8.531664    7.561645    8.172427    6.090729    5.211048    5.419967    3.921543    5.067175    4.272155    3.653463    2.593495    2.604687
```

The data is presented in an external file which is read in by R and so far produces this:

[image]

I am using persp and some messy manual axis labelling for the Delta_T, but it isn't ideal... it would be nice if I could employ the header and label column/row from the matrix, so column/5 is the cycle number and position number is P1 to P12...
Ideally with ticks, and it would be nice to be able to plot the lines for scale at the back too...
(I did fiddle with the volcano sample which can give me grids, but then I can't easily plot it to a pdf as it is more interactive... )

The below is the code I use, but I am open to alternative solutions as well:

```
DataIn <- as.matrix(read.table("Processed Banner Data.txt",row.names=1,header=TRUE))

HiReTSOut <- DataIn[,c(12:1)]

z <- HiReTSOut

## colouring method from a presentation on some R plots
nrz <- nrow(HiReTSOut)
ncz <- ncol(HiReTSOut)

jet.colors <- colorRampPalette( c("blue","green","yellow","orange","red"))
nbcol <- 100
color <- jet.colors(nbcol)
zfacet <- z[-1,-1] + z[-1, -ncz] + z[-nrz,-1] + z[-nrz,-ncz]
facetcol <- cut(zfacet, nbcol)


pdf("HiReTS-Banner.pdf",6,5)
par(mar=c(2,2,1,2))

pmat <- 
persp(
HiReTSOut,
col=color[facetcol],
zlim= range(0,200),
xlab="Cycle Number",
ylab="Position Number",
zlab="\n\nDelta T",
theta=-60,
phi=10,
box=TRUE,
#box=FALSE,
#axes=FALSE
axes=TRUE
)


## Long and messy resurce for axis labelling, but gets the job done (to some extent)
## http://entrenchant.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/custom-tick-labels-in-r-perspective.html

x.axis <- 0:1
min.x <- 0
max.x <- 1
y.axis <- 0:1
min.y <- 0
max.y <- 1
z.axis <- seq(0, 200, by=20)
min.z <- 0
max.z <- 20

tick.start <- trans3d(max.x, min.y, z.axis, pmat)
tick.end <- trans3d(max.x, (min.y - 0.025), z.axis, pmat)
segments(tick.start$x, tick.start$y, tick.end$x, tick.end$y)

tick.start <- trans3d(min.x, max.y, z.axis, pmat)
tick.end <- trans3d(min.x - 0.025 , max.y, z.axis, pmat)
segments(tick.start$x, tick.start$y, tick.end$x, tick.end$y)


labels <- as.character(z.axis)
label.pos <- trans3d(max.x, (min.y - 0.05), z.axis, pmat)
text(label.pos$x, label.pos$y, labels=labels, adj=c(0, NA), cex=0.75)

labels <- as.character(z.axis)
label.pos <- trans3d(min.x, (max.y + 0.1), z.axis, pmat)
text(label.pos$x, label.pos$y, labels=labels, adj=c(1, NA), cex=0.75)


dev.off()
```

I can obviously plot lines with the same method that I plot ticks, BUT that would overlay on the surface and looks a bit ugly...

Given how many plotting questions there are on R, maybe it is possible to develop this into some kind of general Wiki style entry that can help others?